# C: Strings are copied from buffer incorrectly

Tags: c, fopen

I have been working with text files but somehow I have been getting a strange error. When I try to get the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 5th parts of a string (the `':'` is the delimiter), I get a weird response. This is what I am trying to read:
1000:Product:0.75:5:0

And I get this sort of answer:

```
8            |X      |0
75(
```

Here is the code:

```
int main(){
char c,buff[100],prod[30],id[8],stock[8],vendas[8];
int i=0,n=0,num=0;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("products.txt","r+");
printf("Lista de produtos(Num |Produto |Stock |Vendas)\n");
while(fgets(buff,100,fp)){
 for(n=0;n<strlen(buff);n++){
   if(buff[n]==':'){
    num++;
    i=0;
    }       
   else if((buff[n]!=':')&&(num==0)){
    id[i]=buff[n];
    i++;
    }
   else if((buff[n]!=':')&&(num==1)){
    prod[i]=buff[n];
    i++;
    }
   else if((buff[n]!=':')&&(num==3)){
    stock[i]=buff[n];
    i++;
    }
   else if((buff[n]!=':')&&(num=4)){
    vendas[i]=buff[n];
    i++;
    }      
  }
 i=0;
 num=0;
 printf("%s   |%s              |%s      |%s\n",id,prod,stock,vendas);    
 memset(id,0,8);
 memset(prod,0,30);
 memset(stock,0,8);
 memset(vendas,0,8);
 }
printf("Prima qualquer tecla para sair");
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this question or my code isn't the best.
Have a great day!

Comment: `%s` format specifier expects a null-terminated stirng as argument

Comment: Might want to think about terminating those strings as you switch from one state to another.

Comment: You might also think about using strtok to split the string into parts.

Comment: Just noticed that num=4 is incorrect. Already corrected it but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

- In case the format string does not start with `:`, you never initialize `i`.
- In case it does start with `:` then `num==0` will never get executed.
- You never null terminate the strings.
- `if(buff[n]==':')` ... `else if((buff[n]!=':'` is redundant.
- `num=4` is a bug, enable compiler warnings or get a better compiler.
- You never check if the file was opened correctly nor if you reached the end of the file.

Comment: *In case the format string does not start with :, you never initialize I.* He does initialize `I` in the beginning and at the end of the while loop.

Comment: `i` is initialised when it is declared.

Comment: Hmm okay. Why initialize a variable at 3 different locations though... it is designed for maximum confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The fitst time through invokes undefined behaviour because you have not initialised the content of each field buffer.

You also do not check for buffer overruns when filling the fields in. If a field is as long or longer than the array you are putting it in, there will be a buffer overrun and no terminating `\0`

Also in each `else if` you do not need the `(buff[n]!=':')` condition.

Also, the last `else if` has an assignment in the conditional `n = 4` (although this actually does not affect the result).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think you posted your comment on the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least two errors:

Initialize your arrays first before trying to use them...

```
while(fgets(buff,100,fp)){
  memset(id,0,8);
  memset(prod,0,30);
  memset(stock,0,8);
  memset(vendas,0,8);
  for(n=0;n<strlen(buff);n++){
```

Assignment in test, replace:

```
if((buff[n]!=':')&&(num=4)){
```

with

```
if((buff[n]!=':')&&(num==4)){
                        ^
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping so fast! I will keep all your tips in mind. I hope you all have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You may be making the logic much more difficult that it needs to be. When you must break a line of text up into words based on a delimiter, you should be thinking `strtok` or `strsep`. `strtok` is the normal routine used to *tokenize* a line of text on delimiters, breaking the line up into individual words. (`strsep` is primarily used when there is a chance of encountering an *empty-field*, as in a large .csv file).

Your tokens are simple the `':'` char and the `'\n'` at the end. You could simply declare `char *delim = ":\n";` and be covered.

While your are free to daisy-chain `if, then, else if, ....` together, a `switch` on a counter may make life easier and the code more readable.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { ISV = 8, PROD = 30, BUFF = 100 };    /* constants */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buff[BUFF] = "", prod[PROD] = "", id[ISV] = "", 
        stock[ISV] = "", vendas[ISV] = "", *delim = ":\n";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buff, sizeof buff, fp)) { /* for each line of input */
        int i = 0, n = 0;   /* tokenize buff into words */
        for (char *p = strtok (buff, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0: strncpy (id, p, ISV);       /* handle id */
                        if (strlen (p) >= ISV)
                            id[ISV-1] = 0;
                            i++;
                        break;
                case 1: strncpy (prod, p, PROD);    /* handle prod */
                        if (strlen (p) >= PROD)
                            prod[PROD-1] = 0;
                            i++;
                        break;
                case 2: strncpy (stock, p, ISV);    /* handle stock */
                        if (strlen (p) >= ISV)
                            stock[ISV-1] = 0;
                            i++;
                        break;
                case 3: strncpy (vendas, p, ISV);   /* handle vendas */
                        if (strlen (p) >= ISV)
                            vendas[ISV-1] = 0;
                            i++;
                        break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
        n++;

        printf ("id: %s,  prod: %s,  stock: %s,  vendas: %s\n",
                id, prod, stock, vendas);

        if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/prod.txt
1000:Product1:0.75:5:0
1001:Product2:0.90:2:0
1002:Product3:0.55:8:0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/prod dat/prod.txt
id: 1000,  prod: Product1,  stock: 0.75,  vendas: 5
id: 1001,  prod: Product2,  stock: 0.90,  vendas: 2
id: 1002,  prod: Product3,  stock: 0.55,  vendas: 8
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Understood it completely. Will keep those tips in mind in the future.